# Exact centering of full-page background image

Tags: positioning, memoir, geometry, backgrounds

Here's the situation:

1. I have to use `memoir` (v3.6j), with `geometry` (v5.6) and `LuaTeX`, version beta-0.70.1-2011061410 (rev 4277) in an **A5 project** which, in the final output have to be 3mm larger from any side, i.e., PDF dimensions should be **154x216mm**. I use `crop` (v1.9) package for crop marks and setting the correct paper size.
2. The project has two background images, each for both left and right pages, which fit **154x216mm** size. For this purpose, I have to use `eso-pic` (v2.0c) this time (though suggestions regarding `background` and `wallpaper` packages are most welcome).
3. Though I can manually tweak the position of those background images, I'd like to know if there is an automatic way to place them **exactly** centered regarding the page, if possible independent of changing paper dimensions with `crop` package (comment l.13, and uncomment l.14).

Here is a sample document code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\DisemulatePackage{geometry}
\DisemulatePackage{crop}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    papersize={148mm,210mm},%
    hmargin={2cm,2cm},%
    vmargin={2cm,2.2cm},
    showframe}

\usepackage[width=15.4cm,height=21.6cm,center,cam]{crop}
%\usepackage[width=16.3cm,height=22.5cm,center,cam]{crop}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\bgleft}{{\color{yellow}\rule{154mm}{216mm}}}% Background for even pages

\newcommand{\bgright}{{\color{green}\rule{154mm}{216mm}}}% Background for odd pages

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
    {\bgright}%
    {\bgleft}
    }

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) So, just to make it clear, the point here is that background images should fit exactly 154x216mm page. Centering vertically and horizontally against the page dimensions set by `geometry` package would be ideal, since these dimensions are constant and do not change (with a note that background should be allowed to exceed margins and page boundaries), unlike paper dimensions set by `crop` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my shot at it without `crop`, `geometry`, or `eso-pic`.

I'm assuming you need the color to bleed over the trim, and therefore need the background underneath the crop marks (that's what the first, mystical line does).

Note the use of `memoir` dimensions. All you need to do to remove/add the trims is to update `\setstocksize` and `\settrims`

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}\AtBeginShipoutInit
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,showtrims]{memoir}
\setstocksize{216mm}{154mm}
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{148mm}{*}
\settrims{3mm}{3mm}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{22mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\trimLmarks
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\bgleft}{{\color{yellow}\rule{\stockwidth}{\stockheight}}}% Background for even pages
\newcommand{\bgright}{{\color{green}\rule{\stockwidth}{\stockheight}}}% Background for odd pages
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
            {\put(0,-\stockheight){\bgright}}%
            {\put(0,-\stockheight){\bgleft}}%
      }%
}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

---

Following Meho's comments, I went back to the drawing-board, and here's the result. I haven't parameterised the image size, the trimmed size, nor yet the 3mm difference, but I believe this solution works (is correct?, even), for any arbitrary stock size and trimming geometry that ends up at A5 after trimming.

I have halved the size of the coloured backgrounds to help in testing. Their north-east corners correspond to the center point of Meho's images.

Uncomment the lines shown and tinker with the values there -- the coloured boxes should not move relative to the page (and text).

Here it is, then:

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}\AtBeginShipoutInit
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,draft,showtrims,a5paper]{memoir}
\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\settrimmedsize{210mm}{148mm}{*}
% Un-comment to play with stock size and trimming arrangements
% \setstocksize{256mm}{184mm}
% \settrims{10mm}{10mm}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{22mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{30mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\trimLmarks
\newcommand{\bgleft}{{\color{yellow!50}\rule{77mm}{108mm}}}% Background for even pages
\newcommand{\bgright}{{\color{green!50}\rule{77mm}{108mm}}}% Background for odd pages
\newlength{\yboth}
\newlength{\xrecto}
\newlength{\xverso}
\yboth=\dimexpr\trimtop+\paperheight+3mm
\xrecto=\dimexpr\stockwidth-\trimedge-\paperwidth-3mm
\xverso=\dimexpr\trimedge-3mm
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
            {\put(\xrecto,-\yboth){\bgright}}%
            {\put(\xverso,-\yboth){\bgleft}}%
      }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very close to what I want to achieve. The only thing is that `\bgleft` and `\bgright` must not be resized: those will be images with fixed width and height, i.e., exactly 154x216mm, and should be centered always, regardless of changes in `setstocksize`.

Comment: Not to forget, in case you decide to change your example, please don't remove the current code, just comment `\bgleft`, `\bgright` and `\AtBeginShipout` parts and add new ones: This is a great example as it is and it would be shame to remove any part of it.

Comment: I'll accept it because I find both those examples excellent and only because of that ;-) Thanks a lot for your time, much appreciated. You gave me some material to study further, which is a nice bonus :-)

Answer (score 2):

I get exact positioning without `crop`:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    papersize={154mm,216mm},
    layoutsize={148mm,210mm},
    hmargin={2cm,2cm},
    vmargin={2cm,2.2cm}
}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}
    {\kern-62mm\bgright}
    {\bgleft}%
    }
```

However, `showcrop` passed to `\geometry` does nothing, probably because `\AddToShipoutPicture` hooks after `geometry`.

There *should* be a computation that justifies the 62mm. :)

Wouldn't it be simpler to crop the two images right away from the start?

Comment: The point is, I have to deliver pure A5 format for ebook, but for printed version, it was requested of us that background must be +3mm on all sides (plus an even larger version including crop marks). I admit it's a strange request, but I shouldn't question our printer ;-) Of course, there is another approach: just set final dimensions in `geometry`, omit `crop` package completely, and crop PDF after it's compiled, but that isn't really an ideal long-term solution, since I encounter situations like the above quite often.

Comment: BTW, those 62mm are caused for some reason by `memoir` class (try `book` class instead). So, the problem is partially related to using `crop` (larger paper size than page size set by geometry), and partially to `memoir`.

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't need geometry, as memoir has its own, comprehensive layout facilities. Need a little time to play - if I get lucky, more later.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for your insights which (as always), if not solving a problem at once, lead to a better way of doing things. For non-memoir classes, pointing out to `geometry`'s own features `showcrop` and `layoutsize` was crucial and the problem at hand is solved easily, even if done manually. So, again, a big thank you to both of you :-)